# How to get a list of directories though user do not have read permission? C#

Tags: c#, .net, io

I require a list of Directories in C#. I use this line of code to get list of directories in my program.

```
var listDir = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"\\network\path\to\folder\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`
```

It will only give me a list of those directories which I have at least read permission. But I want a list of all those directories which resides under any particular folder irrelevant of permission do I(any other user) have. If it throws an error while accessing a directory that is fine but needs all directories in the list.

How to do the same? In this case, I am clueless and do not have any idea what to do.

Comment: _"It will only give me a list of those directories `which I have` at least `read permission`. But `I want a list of all` those directories which resides under `any particular folder irrelevant of permission`"_ - what you ask is **fundamentally impossible**.  What makes you think security can be bypassed in an adhoc way?  In any event your question is too broad sadly

Comment: 2 possible solutions: Access the directory structure in a privileged user context or prepare a list/tree in a different medium like a database or Xml/Json file.

Comment: @Filburt Can you please explain the second way? As first way is not possible.

Comment: Basically option 2 would mean to create a small (command line) app running by a Scheduled Task to extract the directory structure and store it in a database or file. Of course this is only feasible if you do not need real time data of a highly volatile structure.

Comment: This seems workable and can make changes according to my need. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MickyD sometimes, when you see someone's share folder there are some folders, but when use try to access that folder, system throws an Error that `You do not have permission to access this folder`, then how is that possible? Actually my question is regarding that context only, sorry if it made any wrong impression to you

Comment: @theDarthVader A 3rd way would be creating a WCF service using higher privileges to query the structure for your application - this would make option 1) easier and provide near real time access ... at the cost of adding WCF hosting to your environment.

Comment: I think you could explain your question (much) better. When you say you want a list of all directories under any particular folder, what (minimum) permissions do you expect to have to that particular folder? At least `LIST`? At least `READ`? Perhaps you want `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`?